Dispose not being called for 3 minutes after browser close when using Firefox + Blazor Server
I am using .net 8 blazor server and I have a razor component that implements IDisposable. My dispose method stops and disposes of some timers that are controlling a singleton service. When using firefox the dispose method takes about 3 minutes to get called after the page is closed (not navigated away from).
`@implements IDisposable`

...

// Dispose is taking 3 minutes to call after the page is closed
public void Dispose()
{
    scannerService.Close();
    excitationProbeService.Close();

    connectivityTimer.Stop();
    connectivityTimer.Dispose();

    excitationProbeLoadTimer.Stop();
    excitationProbeLoadTimer.Dispose();

    _logger.LogInformation("Scan Stopped. Disposed of all resources.");
}

On google chrome and edge dispose is called immediately as it should be but when using firefox this is not the case. Is there any workaround for this? Some other way to detect the user has left the page?

Have you tried adding a log event at the start of the method to see if Dispose is being called on time, but the timers are just taking a long time to dispose?

Not a solution, but, there is an event in the NavigationManager for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.locationchanged?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-components-navigationmanager-locationchanged

@LaurenceFrost I did set a breakpoint in the application while debugging on the first line, it takes that long for the first line to be hit
